# Squid proxy - multiple IP addresses

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid

I have got a Ubuntu VPS and I want to turn it to a proxy server with multiple IP addresses, so I can use it for bots.

However, the problem with the proxy I made is that the websites block it because it's only one IP address with different ports and there are too many requests from that one IP address.

Is there any way to get multiple different IP address from one server?

This is my config

```
http_port 3128
http_port 8000
http_port 8080
http_port 8001
http_port 8002
http_port 8003
http_port 8004
http_port 8005
http_port 8006
http_port 8007
http_port 8008
http_port 8009


http_port 49.12.xxx.101:3128 name=3128
http_port 49.12.xxx.101:8000 name=8000
http_port 49.12.xxx.101:8585 name=8080
http_port 49.12.xxx.101:8001 name=8001
http_port 49.12.xxx.101:8002 name=8002
http_port 49.12.xxx.101:8003 name=8003
http_port 49.12.xxx.101:8004 name=8004
http_port 49.12.xxx.101:8005 name=8005
http_port 49.12.xxx.101:8006 name=8006
http_port 49.12.xxx.101:8007 name=8007
http_port 49.12.xxx.101:8008 name=8008
http_port 49.12.xxx.101:8009 name=8009

acl user3 myportname 3128 src all
http_access allow 3128
tcp_outgoing_address 49.12.xxx.101 user3

acl user1 myportname 8000 src all
http_access allow user1
tcp_outgoing_address 2a01:4f8:1c17:6181::2 user1

acl user2 myportname 8080 src all
http_access allow 8080
tcp_outgoing_address 2a01:4f8:1c17:6181::3 user2

acl user3 myportname 8003 src all
http_access allow user3
tcp_outgoing_address 2a01:4f8:1c17:6181::4 user3

acl user4 myportname 8004 src all
http_access allow user4
tcp_outgoing_address 2a01:4f8:1c17:6181::5 user4

acl user5 myportname 8005 src all
http_access allow user5
tcp_outgoing_address 2a01:4f8:1c17:6181::6 user5

acl user6 myportname 8006 src all
http_access allow user6
tcp_outgoing_address 2a01:4f8:1c17:6181::7 user6

acl user7 myportname 8007 src all
http_access allow user7
tcp_outgoing_address 2a01:4f8:1c17:6181::8 user7

acl user8 myportname 8008 src all
http_access allow user8
tcp_outgoing_address 2a01:4f8:1c17:6181::9 user8

acl user9 myportname 8009 src all
http_access allow user9
tcp_outgoing_address 2a01:4f8:1c17:6181::10 user9
```

Answer (score -1):

- Anyways I'll attempt to answer, please correct me if wrong! I'm self
  tought && have no degree's, but there are a few ways to resolve this
  issue.

  1. Most VPS provider/host, say AWS;Linode etc allow you to add multiple ip4 addresses @ an extra cost. Linode has an option under
     network , 1 click and you have an extra ip4 thus releasing the load.
  2. Your ports, why so many? Your ports should look like this: http_port 3128 http_port 1080 (Socks5 port) http_port 5001 (Reverse
     proxy port)

  You want quality not quantity.. those other ports are commonly
  blocked!

  3.Why not use the server's ip6 port as an additoinal out going proxy? http_port ipv6#$# (Whatever your Ip6 is)

  I know some providers have a limit on the amount of ip4's you can add
  to a server but ip6 they have no problem providing,chances are you'll
  get more ipv6.

  Also set your squid.conf to something like this incorperating yorr
  settings for your bot && you should see better results:

  This is just an example tweak where you need it!

  http_port 3128 http_port 5001 http_port 1080 cache deny all
  hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?

  access_log none cache_store_log none cache_log /dev/null

  refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080 refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0%
  1440 refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|?) 0 0% 0 refresh_pattern . 0 20%
  4320

  #acl specialIP src (only if connecting from outside ip) acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1 acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

  acl SSL_ports port 1-65535 acl Safe_ports port 1-65535 acl CONNECT
  method CONNECT acl siteblacklist dstdomain "/etc/squid/blacklist.acl"
  http_access allow manager localhost http_access deny manager

  http_access deny !Safe_ports

  http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports http_access deny siteblacklist
  auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/basic_ncsa_auth
  /etc/squid/passwd

  auth_param basic children 5 auth_param basic realm Squid
  proxy-caching web server auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours acl
  password proxy_auth REQUIRED http_access allow localhost http_access
  allow password http_access allow specialIP http_access deny all

  forwarded_for off request_header_access Allow allow all
  request_header_access Authorization allow all request_header_access
  WWW-Authenticate allow all request_header_access Proxy-Authorization
  allow all request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all
  request_header_access Cache-Control allow all request_header_access
  Content-Encoding allow all request_header_access Content-Length allow
  all request_header_access Content-Type allow all
  request_header_access Date allow all request_header_access Expires
  allow all request_header_access Host allow all request_header_access
  If-Modified-Since allow all request_header_access Last-Modified allow
  all request_header_access Location allow all request_header_access
  Pragma allow all request_header_access Accept allow all
  request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all request_header_access
  Accept-Encoding allow all request_header_access Accept-Language allow
  all request_header_access Content-Language allow all
  request_header_access Mime-Version allow all request_header_access
  Retry-After allow all request_header_access Title allow all
  request_header_access Connection allow all request_header_access
  Proxy-Connection allow all request_header_access User-Agent allow all
  request_header_access Cookie allow all request_header_access All deny
  all

Comment: I'm answering from my mobile so the spacing  isnt coming out correct but im sure you can figure that out

Comment: Sace Hack please [edit] your answer to format it properly. It's perfectly possible to edit from a mobile - I know because I do it myself - but at the moment (and even with the attempted fix-up by someone else) it's a mess

Comment: @roaima:  I agree that authors should learn how to write, but why undo Greenonline’s edit?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' because it didn't actually improve any of the important parts - the lines are still jumbled together and then even more so because of the code formatting that had been applied. It gave a veneer of formatting without the value that such formatting would add, and by rolling back it becomes (remains) quite clear that the OP hasn't taken care of any of the formatting at all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).